# option to disable generating internal fields in stuct using google protobuf implementation for golang

Tags: protocol-buffers

We are migrating our code base from gogo/protobuf to second version of google.golang.org/protobuf.
We are running into several issues because the new structs have some internal fields namely:-

```
state         protoimpl.MessageState
sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields
```

As a result of these proto.equal doesnt work anymore on these structs and we cannot compare maps  and slices.
More importantly we cannot pass these structures as value since it complains with below error:-
copies lock value: waf_rules.GlobalSpecType contains google.golang.org/protobuf/internal/impl.MessageState contains sync.Mutex

Is there any option to disable generating these internal fields for the structs
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear but I suspect that you're using the protobuf stubs in your application code and you probably should not do so. A good practice is to have application types and map these to|from protobuf-generated types. The protobuf-generated types should then only be used to move messages onto|off channels.

Comment: Basically for the generated code we dont want the internal fields to be generated in the struct:-

Comment: @golang_programmer Did you fix that somehow? I got the same problem, and I cannot find a workaround..